# Наложить один ImageView на другой

Tags: android, android-layout

Как правильно наложить один ImageView на второй, чтобы было как на картинке и чтобы при разных разрешениях картинка с буквой не съезжала. Я это сделала через margin-ны, но хотелось бы узнать более лучшее решение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для такого простого наложения не нужно ничего особенного выдумывать и делать какие то вычесления в коде или использовать "тяжелые" контейнры, вроде `RelativeLayout`. Все просто, как спинка минтая:

Подготавливаете два изображения: большое, с картинкой, и маленькое, с буквой и прозрачным фоном, таким образом, чтобы при совмещении большого с маленьким по верхнему левому углу получился ожидаемый результат (здесь черный контур - большое изображение, красный контур - маленькое).

[image: scrn]

Теперь разметка, используем для наложения самый легкий контейнер - `FrameLayout` (особенность его в том, что все размещение элементов внутри контейнера идет от верхнего левого края, если не указано свойство `gravity`):

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/letter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

На разных экранах эти изображения будут пропорционально масштабироваться, сохраняя приемлемое взаиморасположение. Для лучшего эффекта рекомендуется подготовить несколько альтернативных ресурсов (отдельно для экранов HDPI, XHDPI и тд.)

Comment: Спасибо. Доберусь до компьютера и проверю :)

Answer (score 2):

Как верно подметил **pavlofff**, есть хороший вариант с использованием `FrameLayout`. Доработаем его немного, чтобы он не зависел от наличия прозрачных отступов в самой картинке и действовал для любого размера фонового изображения и любого размера экрана:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/letter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

регулируйте атрибут `android:layout_margin="10dp"` у фонового изображения, чтобы добиться приемлемого расположения буквы относительно картинки.

Comment: как раз "чистое" изображение, с необходимыми относительными размерами заложенными в его собственный размер (прозрачные отступы в самом накладываемом изображении), будет масштабироваться гораздо лучше, чем "подгонка" маржинами

Comment: Для такого подхода надо подгонять все картинки вручную. Но тогда зачем останавливаться на этом? Ведь можно сделать сразу одну картинку с наложенной буквой, что будет еще проще в плане разметки :) Я не знаю ситуации у человека, потому пусть останутся варианты между перерисовкой картинок и подгонкой разметки, чтобы был выбор :)

Answer (score 0):

конкретно в вашем случаем можно обойтись разными хитростями, но в принципе у ImageView есть параметр pivot, отвечающий за точку к которой закреплен рисунок. установить эту точку можно через команды:

```
    imageView.setPivotX();    
    imageView.setPivotY();
```

или аналогичные поля в xml. Если к примеру вы установите pivot буквы по центру картинки а pivot заднего фона в точку где центр буквы будет находится и потом эти два центра совместите margin-ами в любой одной точке, то вы сможете вращать, масштабировать и подменять буквы на фоне сохраняя их расположение относительно друг друга.

В самом просто случае когда картинка и фона начинается в левом верхнем углу контейнера изменение точки привязки будет.

```
    int pivotX = letter.getWidth()/2;
    int pivotY = letter.getHeight()/2;
    letter.setPivotX(pivotX);    
    letter.setPivotY(pivotY);
    background.setPivotX(pivotX);    
    background.setPivotY(pivotY);
```

те же значения сохранятся и для margin-ов чтобы достать картинку из угла родительского Layout-а.